# Android services explanation

Tags: android

Android service is a component that is used to perform operations on the background such as playing music, handle network transactions, interacting content providers etc. **It doesn't has any UI (user interface).**

this is definition of service I read all the time. But Content provider is service and it has UI?? Am I right?

Also there are 3 types of services: foreground, background and bound services

- Is content provider foreground service?
- Is scheduling service background service?

Comment: "But Content provider is service and it has UI?" -- no. "Also there are 3 types of services: foreground, background and bound services" -- no. Foreground/background is independent of whether the service is bound or not. "Is content provider foreground service?" -- no. "Is scheduling service background service?" -- sorry, but I do not know what you mean by "scheduling service".

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

"Also there are 3 types of services: foreground, background and bound services" -- no. 
Are you sure about this no? Not mean to be rude just showing the things I red. This is Android developers site, I don't know is anything more trustworthy than it...

Comment: "Are you sure about this no?" -- yes, because that particular bit of documentation is poorly written. Whether you create the service via `startService()` or `bindService()` is independent of whether the service itself calls `startForeground()` or not. "I don't know is anything more trustworthy than it" -- I have filed many bug reports for the documentation.

Comment: As you can read here [https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Components] , a Content provider is a component separate from a Service. It is not a Service, so the definition of a Service is irrelevant. Also, if you build you app with the proper separation of concerns, a Content provider does not have any UI. Only a Activity (and it descendants) displays UI.

Comment: This really sucks. I spent time reading things and now I realize everything i red is wrong?
I red that content provider is service and now its not.

Ok to summarize this:
- content provider is not a service
- there are 2 types of services: foreground and background
- Content provider (CP) can be created without UI. If we use CP for taking image from gallery, what is the part where we choose image. It is not considered to be CP's UI..?